# Значение переменной в сбилженной версии игры отличается от значения в самом движке. Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть две переменные которые отвечают за чувствительность мыши и скрипт отвечающий за поворот камеры, который использует эти 2 переменные. Когда я тестирую это в самом Unity никаких проблем нету, но когда я делаю билд под PC и тестирую там, то чувствительность существенно падает.

Я вывел значение обоих переменных на экран и обнаружил что их значение равно 15 и в Unity и в билд версии. Вот скрипт в котором происходит объявления переменных:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public static class Models {
    [Serializable]
    public class PlayerSettingsModel {
        [Header("Настройки камеры")]
        public float ViewXSensivity = 15.0f;
        public float ViewYSensivity = 15.0f;
    }
}
```

Вот скрипт камеры:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using static Models;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {
    private CharacterController characterController;
    private DefaultInput defaultInput;
    private Vector2 inputMovement;

    [HideInInspector]
    public Vector2 inputView;

    private Vector3 newCameraRotation, newCharacterRotation;

    [Header("Настройки объектов")]
    public Transform cameraHolder;

    [Header("Настройки")]
    public PlayerSettingsModel playerSettings;
    public float viewClampYMin = -70f;
    public float viewClampYMax = 80f;
    public LayerMask playerMask;

    private void Awake()
    {
        defaultInput = new DefaultInput();

        defaultInput.Character.Movement.performed += e => inputMovement = e.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        defaultInput.Character.View.performed += e => inputView = e.ReadValue<Vector2>();

        defaultInput.Enable();

        newCameraRotation = cameraHolder.localRotation.eulerAngles;
        newCharacterRotation = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;

        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        CalculateView();
    }

    private void CalculateView()
    {
        newCharacterRotation.y += playerSettings.ViewXSensivity * (playerSettings.ViewXInverted ? -inputView.x : inputView.x) * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(newCharacterRotation);

        newCameraRotation.x += playerSettings.ViewYSensivity * (playerSettings.ViewYInverted ? inputView.y : -inputView.y) * Time.deltaTime;
        newCameraRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(newCameraRotation.x, viewClampYMin, viewClampYMax);

        cameraHolder.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(newCameraRotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: А что показывает переменная ```newCharacterRotation.y``` в обоих версиях?

Comment: Попробуйте вывести Time.deltaTime. А вообще в unity уже всё это есть (в том числе и возможность модифицировать и сохранять настройки) с помощью Input